# Can we write for loop in HPQC/ALM Query builder

Tags: oracle, query-builder, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

I am using HPQC/ALM version 11.00 and I want to write an sql statement that retrieve the number of step that passed, failed, blocked, etc... for each run id.

I tried to write a for loop, but query builder throws 'Quality Center cannot run the query because it contains invalid statement'

```
select runids in (select rn_run_id from run)
loop
select r.rn_run_id from run r where r.rn_run_id = runids.rn.run_id
end loop;
```

db type = oracle

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `runids` as a cursor variable for your driving query. Likewise, the inner SELECT must be assigned to a variable. Something like this:

```
for runids in (select rn_run_id from run)
loop
    select r.rn_run_id 
    into l_run_id
    from run r 
    where r.rn_run_id = runids.rn.run_id;
end loop;
```